# Who is the highest-grossing female director?

Tags: directors, box-office

Wikipedia's [list of highest-grossing directors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_directors) shows that the top 10 highest grossing directors are all male. Who is the highest grossing female director? And how does she rank with other male directors?

I'm mostly interested in solo directors, but I suppose it would be worth noting the highest grossing female co-director, if she has a higher gross than the highest grossing female solo director.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Box Office Mojo has a more comprehensive [list of directors](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/people/?view=Director&pagenum=2&sort=sumgross&order=DESC&&p=.htm) that you can sort by box office gross.

As of this writing, [The Wachowskis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wachowskis) are the top-grossing female co-directors, since they [both now identify as trans women](http://www.theguardian.com/film/2016/mar/09/matrix-director-lilly-wachowski-comes-out-as-a-transgender-woman) (although much of their box-office gross was made when they publicly identified as men). They, of course, are the directors of *The Matrix* films, and share 65th place overall on the list of directors. The two are often classified as a single director on lists of this sort since all of their directorial work has been together.

[Nancy Myers](http://www.boxofficemojo.com/people/chart/?view=Director&id=nancymeyers.htm) is the top-grossing solo female director, whose top-grossing film was *[What Women Want](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0207201/)* starring Mel Gibson and Helen Hunt. Myers comes in 85th place overall.

Comment: That raises an interesting question of boundaries to this question, as I believe they were both identifying as men when they achieved most of that gross.

Comment: @T.E.D. I think that's a valid point. They were both identifying as male (at least publicly) when the very large majority of that box office gross was made.

Comment: My question mentioned that I was looking for a solo director, so Nancy Myers definitely seems to be the right answer. However, I did say that it would be useful to add co-directors if they were higher grossing, so adding the Wachowskis makes sense, with an asterisk that they publicly identified as male when the majority of their gross was made.

Comment: Could you please add how much Nancy Myers grossed, as of 2016 (or 2015, if that makes more sense)? Also, perhaps the answer can be refocused around her, since she is the highest grossing solo director, which is what I was looking for.

Comment: @Thunderforge - I don't think the Wachowskis do much without each other, so it seems fair to consider them together as a single "director" for the purposes of your question.

Comment: Actually, would [Jennifer Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jennifer_Lee_(filmmaker)) be the highest grossing female co-director? She co-directed *Frozen*, which seems to have grossed far more than the the Wachowskis' works.

Comment: @Thunderforge For a single film, it looks like she'd take the top spot. *Frozen* is her only director credit to date, though, so she's got a way to go before she claims the top spot overall. If she keeps working for Disney, this answer should be outdated very soon.